# Serialize an object with "query" property name using Jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have the following class:

```
public class ParameterDef {
    private string type;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private Map<String, String> query;
    ...
}
```

When I try to serialize it, the "query" property is never generated:

```
    "Parameter" : {
      "type" : "string",
      "title" : "title...",
      "description" : "description..."
    }
```

But if I change in my class the property name "query" to "Query" for example,

`Map<String, String> Query;`

I'm able to generated it:

```
    "Parameter" : {
      "type" : "string",
      "title" : "title...",
      "description" : "description...",
      "Query" : {
        "1111" : "1111",
        "2222" : "2222"
      }
    }
```

I tried also with the @JsonProperty tag,

```
@JsonProperty("query")
Map<String, String> Query;
```

but without succeed, "query" property is not generated.

I need to have this "query" property name in my json. Thanks for any help!

Comment: It works with jackson 2.12.2 , maybe the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @dariosicily  Thanks for your help.  I tried on 2.12.2 and I have the same problem.  In your side you are able to generate this type of json with a property named "query" ?

Comment: @dariosicily  I found the cause of my problem that comes from an other side as you wrote. Thanks for you help.

Comment: I voted to close this question because you indicate that you resolved the problem without receiving any answers.

Comment: @Stephen  I'm ok to close it but I don't know how to proceed.. :)

Comment: You could add your own answer to your question saying what worked.  If you did that, it could help other people with similar problems and this question wouldn't need to be closed.

Comment: The problem I had is that I had let @JsonIgnoreProperties({"query"}) property in my code.